# Why do I get no response when using the JS Path to retrieve results from a website using Playwright and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, playwright

I am trying to use JavaScript and the Playwright library to get the results from an online casino game. I managed to login normally and go to the specific url for the game.

When I inspect the element that displays the results and use the console, I get the result. The problem is that when I copy the JS Path and paste it to the code and run it I get no response.

Here's the code I am using to retrieve the result:

```
import {firefox, webkit, chromium} from 'playwright'
(async () => {
const browser = await firefox.launch({
headless: false
})
const page = await browser.newPage()

await page.goto('https://www.playpix.com/');
await page.goto('https://www.playpix.com/pb/');
await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Aceitar' }).click();
await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Entrar' }).click();
await page.getByLabel('Email / Usuário').click();
await page.getByLabel('Email / Usuário').fill('mrooc@me.com');
await page.getByLabel('Email / Usuário').press('Tab');
await page.getByLabel('Senha').click();
await page.getByLabel('Senha').fill('thepassword');
await page.locator('form').getByRole('button', { name: 'Entrar' }).click();
await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
await page.waitForTimeout(4000)

await page.goto('https://www.playpix.com/pb/?openGames=217032-real&gameNames=Football%20Studio'); 
await page.waitForTimeout(20000)
while (true) {

    // Wait for the element to be visible
    var result = document.querySelector("#root > div > div.app--2c5f6 > div > div.content--82383 > div.footerWrapper--3a742 > div > div.footer--0ff51.right--c3d03 > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > svg > g > text");

    // Print the text content
    console.log(result.textContent());

}

})();
```

I am using the While loop to try to get the results as they are updated in intervals of 30s more or less.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: There's a lot of reasons for this not to be working. You will need to add much more detail about the specific use case for anyone to be able to debug the problem. That being said, the use of `while (true)` is a ***massive*** code smell. You absolutely need to remove that and use something like a MutationObserver instead to detect when the DOM changes

Comment: Ok, I update the question to display all the code.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` won't work on the node side. You need to locate the element and the evaluate a javascript expression:

```
var result = await page
  .locator("#root > div > div.app--2c5f6 > div > div.content--82383 > div.footerWrapper--3a742 > div > div.footer--0ff51.right--c3d03 > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > svg > g > text")
    .evaluate(node => node.textContent());

// Print the text content
console.log(result);
```

Comment: No response either.

Comment: What do you mean with "no response"? Empty string?

Comment: No, I get no response. Nothing on the output.

Comment: If you run that in the browser do you get any value?

Comment: Yes, within the browser I get the results.